# Dynamic linking error with statically linked boost library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am on Windows(MSVC 2012) and with Boost v1.54, I compiled **Boost.Log** (my small project depends on it) with following parameters:

```
b2.exe link=static variant=release runtime-link=shared --with-log stage
```

So the log module is compiled and dynamically linked to C Runtime Library.

Then my small project uses **CMake** to manage, and I add option to link boost statically:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

But make process of generated nmake makefile failed, with link error 2038:

```
libboost_log-vc110-mt-1_54.lib(attribute_set.obj):-1: error: LNK2038:
  mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't
  match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in http_proxy_server.cpp.obj
```

But if I compile boost with option `runtime-link=static`, means linking CRT statically, then I can successfully make my project.

My question is: Could someone explain why my project failed to link with the CRT dynamically linked version of boost, but succeeded with the CRT statically linked version of boost, what's the difference?

BTW: my project is dynamically linked to CRT with `/MD` option.

---

**Edit:**

Finally I figured out the reason, I mixed up `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, the former has a `/MD` option, but the latter does not. In fact cmake will pass the latter to compiler, so my program is actually linked statically as the error output shows.

Solution: run cmake with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` when generating makefile, this will add options of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` into `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` automatically, then the program will be linked to CRT dynamically.

Oh, a silly question.

Comment: The error message suggests that `http_proxy_server.cpp` is being compiled to use `MT_StaticRelease` of the library. Could that be the reason? How is that translation unit being compiled?

Comment: @greatwolf Compile? Maybe Link you mean? My project is dynamically linked to CRT by `/MD` option, but statically linked to boost library.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508369/boost-libs-building-difference-between-runtime-link-and-link-options

Comment: Have you tried adding set( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF ) ?

Comment: @Daarx I tried, the error still exists.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto Thanks for the useful link. In the answer there is a paragraph `The runtime-link option you use when building Boost should match the option when you're using for your client code. Otherwise you'll get errors due to mismatched runtime either at link time or upon running your program.`, this seems to be the root cause, but I built boost with dynamic runtime, and also built my program with dynamic runtime, they are matched.

Comment: Have you set the /MD option manually in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS? IIRC when I encountered a similar problem this seemed to fix things even though the generated visual studio project supposedly had the flag set, as well. I have no idea why it fixed things for me, though.

Comment: @Daarx Yeah, finally I figured out the reason, it is the improper setting of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, please see the *edit* section of this question.

Comment: @Kelvin Please answer this question using the answer form below. Even if it is your own question you are answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this question is asked by myself, and finally I figured out the reason, and I pasted the solution in the **Edit** section of the question. But @TobiMcNamobi suggests to give this question an answer even it is asked by myself. So I paste the answer here:

I mixed up `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, the former has a `/MD` option, but the latter does not. In fact cmake will pass the latter to compiler, so my program is actually linked statically as the error output shows.

Solution: run cmake with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` when generating makefile, this will add options of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` into `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` automatically, then the program will be linked to CRT dynamically.